# How can I count number of "xxx" in string c++?

Tags: c++, string, count, character

I want to count number of `xxx` in string `s` and I tried this:

`cn2=count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'xxx');`
and this is the problem: `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|`

then I tried this:

`cn2=count(s.begin(), s.end(), "xxx");`

but we should enter character in `count` parameters.

Comment: std::count can only count single characters. You could write your own algorithm to do this using std::search instead though

Comment: @Tharwen with std::search? How?

Comment: Remy Lebeau described how to do it with std::find, which is very similar

Comment: @ParisaMousavi I added a `std::search()` example to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) in a loop, eg:

```cpp
int count = 0;
std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = s.find("xxx", pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    ++count;
    pos += 3;
}
```

Or [`std::search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int count = 0;
std::string sub = "xxx";
std::string::iterator iter = s.begin();
while ((iter = std::search(iter, s.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end())) != s.end())
{
    ++count;
    iter += sub.size();
}
```